# Boolean creates open mesh / hollow

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have been trying to modify a STL file from thingiverse to hold a boat I modeled up. However, when I use the boolean difference operator it creates a hole in the mesh rather than forming around the subtracted object! AHHHH so frustrating. Does anyone know what's going on?[image]

Comment: Make sure both Meshes are Manifold. In Edit mode use the Selection menu to find non-Manifold faces/edges and fix them.

Comment: Is the imported stl model watertight?

Comment: @rob I couldn't find any non-manifold faces or edges...

Comment: @rjg i believe the model is watertight. It appears to be fully enclosed

Comment: do you know how I can share so you would be able to see?

Comment: You can upload your project here (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and add the generated link to your question.

Comment: @rjg just uploaded the file called "untitled"! let me know what you think. Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6754" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6754/)